# Why can't git post-receive hook find single file in repo?

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04, githooks, git-post-receive

I have this git post-receive hook

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/myproject --git-dir=/home/git/myrepo.git checkout -f -- api.py
```

And the local repo simply contains a `.git` folder and a `api.py` file.

When I push the project I get the following error:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 272 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: pathspec 'myrepo/api.py' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I have also tried adding the full file path `myrepo/api.py` to the git hook and it gave the same error for that path.

What is the correct way to reference that file I'm trying to move? The remote computer is ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your checkout by a `git status` to see if you are on the right branch.

Try to specify a branch:

```
 git --work-tree=/var/www/myproject --git-dir=/home/git/myrepo.git checkout master -f -- api.py
```